# Jigsaw Modules (Command Line/no IDE): java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found, required by main.java.com.injection.configuration

Tags: java, windows, command-line, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to learn the "new" Jigsaw Module system and I'm trying to build a simple application from scratch via the Windows command line / no IDE (because it is necessary for the oracle certificate).

Now I have the problem that my application needs some javaFX modules which I have all defined in my module-info.java file:

```
module main.java.com.injection.configuration{

requires javafx.base;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.graphics;
```

}

I copied the jar files (all javafx jars are modules too) from Maven repo and put them in the mods folder.

After that I compiled the application successfully.

```
$ javac --module-path mods/ -d out/ src/main/java/com/injection/configuration/*.java src/main/java/com/injection/injection/*.java src/main/java/com/injection/views/*.java src/module-info.java
```

`Note: src\main\java\com\injection\injection\Injector.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.`'

But as soon as I try to run the application, following exception is thrown (although all necessary jars are in the folder):

```
$ java --module-path out/ --module main.java.com.injection.configuration/main.java.com.injection.configuration.Configuration
```

`Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found, required by main.java.com.injection.configuration`

Please can you help me? What is the right way to deal with "external" jars (e.g.: from the openjfx sdk) via command line
Kind Regards